# Update an IFRAME URL within a Dialog Window using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to update a URL to an IFRAME located in a Dialog Window. Seems simple but for some reason the URL will not update.

This is the code that creates the IFRAME:

```
var page = "/detail.aspx?id=" + rs_array.selected_records + "&pageNumber=" + pageNumber;
//alert(page);
$("<div id='edit_record' />").dialog({ 
        modal: true, 
        closeonescape: true, 
        width: 1500,  
        height: 600,
        border: 2,
        position: {my: "center", at: "center", of: window}, 
        title: toProperCase(str_action) + " " + toProperCase(active_panel.replace(/[_]/g, ' ')), 
        dialogClass: "form_dialog" }).html('<iframe id="ifManifestDetail" style="border: 0px;" src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>');
$("#edit_record").dialog({
    close: function () {
        fc_refresh_datasheet(active_panel);
        $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
    }
});
```

Here is the code that I'm using to try and update the IFRAME:

```
$('#ifManifestDetail').src('/summary.aspx');
```

I also tried

```
$('#ifManifestDetail').attr('src', '/pds_login.asp');
```

Neither are working.

Comment: did my solution work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve my problem I had to use Javascript window.location in order to change the Dialog src.

Answer (score 0):

try `$('#ifManifestDetail').attr('src','/summary.aspx');`

ok just saw your updated question

use absolute url for iframe. `'http://www.domain.com/summary.aspx'` instead `'/summary.aspx'`

`$('#ifManifestDetail').attr('src','http://your-domain.com/summary.aspx');`

Comment: I tried the absolute reference as well and the IFRAME stays on the original page.

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying now?it will be very helpfull if you can share in plunker or as a snippet

Comment: not familiar with those tools, we can start a chat if that helps. Quick note I did try and verify that the IFRAME is visible and the result is false

Comment: The interesting thing is I can access the contents of the IFRAME using $('#ifManifestDetail').contents().find(XXXXX....)

Comment: you will have to send me a link, I don't seem to have the ability to issue a chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104794/discussion-between-pavan-teja-and-jrobinson6274).